# javascript convert elements of an array into array for themselves

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I convert the elements of the array into another array?

```
let a = [2, 4, 0, 8, 9, 15]
```

and the result will be :

```
a = [[2], [4], [0], [8], [9], [15]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array, and wrap each item in an array:

```js
let a = [2, 4, 0, 8, 9, 15]

const result = a.map((n) => [n])

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: What type of nomenclature is "Array#map" supposed to be?

Comment: It's an old MDN way of naming methods, which you can paste to the location box in the browser, and it will find the article in mdn, instead of trying to get to the website.

Comment: What benefit does it have today?

Comment: Mainly me being used to it :)

Comment: You might be used to it, but you're educating others here.

Comment: Other people used this nomenclature as well. Some of them still do. I also use it mainly as a basis for a link to the article. I'm sure nobody ever tried to map with Array#map.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = [2, 4, 0, 8, 9, 15];
let b = a.map((item) => [item]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    a = [2, 4, 0, 8, 9, 15]
    console.log(result = a.map((n) => [n]))
    b=[]
//you can try  below also
     for (i in a){
      b.push([i]);
      }
```